# How to increase the height of Android screen (Android studio device)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-scrollview

As you can see with this photo :

[image: android device form]

I'm creating a form who is not complete due to the height of the Android screen (I can't add new button, text etc).

I searched on the internet how to change the height of the screen , so I could finish my form.

People say to add a `ScrollView`

So i added it in my layout XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_form"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">


<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.FormActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Ajouter Votre Annonce" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Entrer le Titre de votre Annonce"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: Add them in the xml file, they will not be shown in the preview, but when you hover with the mouse over the layout in the preview and scroll the wheel you will see the new items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the above views while you are creating the below views by doing visibility GONE. Then it will show new views in the preview. After you are done just remove the visibility tag from above views and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 4):

Switch to "Text" and write it manually. Or simply drag the layout to make it longer. [image]

Comment: im unable to drag the layout (blocked) but i think ill use android visibility : gone to have free space , or just write manually in the xml file . thanks

Comment: You have to select "Custom" in the menu above the preview where you're supposed to select a device

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try switching to another device? You are currently testing on "Nexus 4". 
[image]

Note: I think what you really must do– is to adjust jour form field heights to fit into small screens too!